# Set value to math in JS?

Tags: javascript, hex

```
function myFunction() {
var var1 = 5;
var var2 = 50;
var var3 = 100;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + (255-var1) + (255-var2) + (255-var3);
};
```

How can I convert the value inside the parentheses to hexadecimal value?
Ultimately, the value would be #FACD9B (Just an example)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you're actually asking how to convert to hexadecimal.

Comment: `How can I make it do the math` You've done the math.. by executing `255-x` inside the parentheses. right? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"#" + (255-var1).toString(16) + (255-var2).toString(16) + (255-var3).toString(16)
```

Comment: you ask the provided number to be converted to `base16`

Comment: @Dr.Owning Because hexadecimal is base 16. Instead of 10 it'll show `a`, then for 11 show `b`, etc

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString see this for reference

Answer (score 4):

You could use rgb instead of hex color codes in order to make it particularly simple, as well.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor= 'rgb(' + (255-var1) + ',' + (255-var2) + ',' + (255-var3) + ')';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a color via three variables, what you want is probably RGB format (x, y, z), not hex (#xxxxxx). So it'd be something like:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 
"rgb(" + (255-var1) + "," + (255-var2) + "," + (255-var3) + ")"
```

which would output something like

```
"rgb(247,205,155)"
```

which is a valid way to declare a color in CSS/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

Which tells about the rgbtohex function by @Tim Down

Use it like this

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgbToHex(var1, var2, var3);
```